# Copy list of file names from multiple directories

Tags: list, batch-file, vbscript, copy

i'm new to the forum. I need some advice. I need help with a code to take a text file with a list of file names and copy the files from multiple folders in to one folder, but it has to end up with the most recent modified date of the file. There are hundreds of folders containing the thousands of files.

I have a batch code below to copy the files, but it does not always end up with the newest file. **If there is some way to make the code below search the folders in numerical order, that would work instead of it searching in a random order.** I do not care if the code i end up using is batch, vbs, or whatever.

```
mkdir %userprofile%\desktop\print
set FIILELIST=%userprofile%\desktop\print.txt
set FILESPATH="\\server\folder"
set DESTPATH=%userprofile%\desktop\print

for /f %%X in (%FIILELIST%) do call :COPY_FILES "%%X"
goto :eof

:COPY_FILES
for /r %FILESPATH% %%I in (%~1) do copy "%%I" "%DESTPATH%"
```

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't always get the newest file?

Comment: Most recently modified date of *what* file? Are files with the same name scattered across multiple folders and you want the most recent one of them?

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. I couldn't come up with a clear way to say that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /r %FILESPATH% %%I in (%~1) do Xcopy /D "%%I" "%DESTPATH%"
```

`XCOPY /D` will only copy if the destination file does not exist or if the destination file is older than the source.

Comment: Great! Thanks! i cant believe i didnt get that.