# Batch copy files from text list of file names in linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a list of images in a text file in the following format:

```
abc.jpg
xyz.jpg
```

The list contains about a hundred images in various directories within a specific directory. I would like to create a shell script that finds and copies these files into a specified directory.

Can this script be adapted to what I need?
[Copy list of file names from multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148607/copy-list-of-file-names-from-multiple-directories)

Answer (score 5):

you do not need a script for this, a simple oneliner will do:
(assuming, that the full filepath, or the relative filepath to were you executing the command is written in your_file.txt file for every image)

```
cat your_file.txt | xargs find path_to_root_dir -name | xargs -I{} cp {} specfic_directory/
```

xargs will take multiple lines and runs the command you give it with the input of every line with -I you can specify a variable, for where the content of the line is placed in the command (default is at the end).

So this will take every line from you file, search the file in all subdirectories of path_to_root_dir and then does a copy.

Comment: I should have specified that. In the text file I have only the filename, the files themselves are scattered in various directories.

Comment: I'm getting an error:
    find: paths must precede expression: abc.jpg

Comment: did you change 'path_to_root_dir' to your needs?

Comment: Yes, path_to_root_dir is set to the directory that contains the images. Note that the images are in sub-directories from that root directory. specific_dir is set to the directory where files should be moved to, correct?

Comment: no, its meant to be the directory under which all the images are (in subdirectories) in an extreme case that might be /home or even /

Comment: try also to split up the pipline to see whats going on like try running ```cat your_file.txt | xargs find path_to_root_dir -name``` and see what it gives you

Comment: I have path_to_root_dir as /home (files are in directory in /home/user/Desktop, so that should be appropriate). Even running that part of the phrase, I am getting the same error as above. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128579/discussion-between-brett-and-zabeltech).

Comment: The file in error is the second one in the txt filenames list. This may have the solution: http://superuser.com/questions/623439/using-xargs-with-find -- I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Using `xargs -L 1 find root_dir_name"` worked for me